# Can we use pytorch scatter_ on GPU

Tags: gpu, pytorch, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to do one hot encoding on some data with pyTorch on GPU mode, however, it keeps giving me an exception. Can anybody help me?

Here's one example:

```py
def char_OneHotEncoding(x):
    coded = torch.zeros(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 101)
    for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        coded[:,i] = scatter(x[:,i])
    return coded


def scatter(x):
    return torch.zeros(x.shape[0], 101).scatter_(1, x.view(-1,1), 1)
```

So if I give it an tensor on GPU, it shows like this:

```py
x_train = [[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [14, 13, 83, 18, 14],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]
print(char_OneHotEncoding(torch.tensor(x_train, dtype=torch.long).cuda()).shape)
```

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-95c0c4ade406> in <module>()
      4        [14, 13, 83, 18, 14],
      5        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]
----> 6 print(char_OneHotEncoding(torch.tensor(x_train, dtype=torch.long).cuda()).shape)
      7 x_train[:5, maxlen:maxlen+5]

<ipython-input-53-055f1bf71306> in char_OneHotEncoding(x)
      2     coded = torch.zeros(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 101)
      3     for i in range(x.shape[1]):
----> 4         coded[:,i] = scatter(x[:,i])
      5     return coded
      6 

<ipython-input-53-055f1bf71306> in scatter(x)
      7 
      8 def scatter(x):
----> 9     return torch.zeros(x.shape[0], 101).scatter_(1, x.view(-1,1), 1)

RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #3 'index'
```

BTW, if we simply remove the `.cuda()` here, everything goes one well

```py
print(char_OneHotEncoding(torch.tensor(x_train, dtype=torch.long)).shape)
```

```sh
torch.Size([5, 5, 101])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to pay attention that *all* tensors are on GPU. In particular, by default, constructors like `torch.zeros` allocate on CPU, which will lead to this kind of mismatches. Your code can be fixed by constructing with `device=x.device`, as below

```
import torch

 def char_OneHotEncoding(x):
     coded = torch.zeros(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 101, device=x.device)
     for i in range(x.shape[1]):
         coded[:,i] = scatter(x[:,i])
     return coded


 def scatter(x):
     return torch.zeros(x.shape[0], 101, device=x.device).scatter_(1, x.view(-1,1), 1)

 x_train = torch.tensor([
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
     [14, 13, 83, 18, 14],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
 ], dtype=torch.long, device='cuda')

 print(char_OneHotEncoding(x_train).shape)
```

Another alternative are constructors called `xxx_like`, for instance [`zeros_like`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.zeros_like), though in this case, since you need different shapes than `x`, I found `device=x.device` more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is indeed where the problem is!